# How to dynamically add a class just to one value in li?

Tags: css, vue.js, dynamically-generated

I have an unordered list that iterates over object. The object stores two key/value pairs: One is the discriptive label of the row, and the other is the stored numeric value. However, when i iterate over them, they are displayed next to each other, and i want to space them a bit. How can i do that?

```
<ul>
 <li
  v-for="item in shiftOrderProductivity"
  :key="item"
 >{{ item.label }} {{ item.value }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you just need to assign css class to parent `<ul>` and then use it to set `<li>` elements with either margin-right property set, or set to be displayed as block if needed to be one below another.

Comment: also, your question title is not of same issue as question explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `&nbsp;` which is a **built-in HTML white space**. However, that's what I consider a **little bit of space**, for more space you can apply **margin** to your li tags.

Thus, in your case you can do something like this:

```
{{ item.label }} &nbsp; {{ item.value }}
```

**Update:**

Alternatively, for more space you use `<pre>` tag to pre-format text. It instructs the browser that the text is to appear **exactly as written** in the HTML file, including any spaces or blank lines. The code would look like this;

```
<ul>
 <li
  v-for="item in shiftOrderProductivity"
  :key="item"
 ><pre>{{ item.label }} **as much space as you need** {{ item.value }}</pre></li>
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your suggestion! &nbsp; Works, but as you said, it's a "little bit of space".
What i'm actually trying to do is this - right now, the label/value combo look like this:
Produced amount: 35 000.
I want to make it look like this:
Produced amount:                                                        35 000.

Comment: You mean the dash ?

Comment: I mean
`{{ item.label }} ~70px whitespace {{ item.value }}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li
     v-for="item in shiftOrderProductivity"
     :key="item"
  ><span class="mr-100">{{ item.label }}</span>{{ item.value }}</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.mr-100 {
   margin-right: 100px;
}
```